# Dynamic control 'ID' automatically added to 'name' attribute, instead of ID attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a couple of lists on a configuration page in my application where users can configure the order of items as well as the selection for specific application pages. I'm using the ID of the dynamic controls added at runtime to move them from A to B, but currently this doesn't work due to my JavaScript failing to retrieve the ID of the control selected.

After digging down and inspecting further, the dynamic controls aren't getting an ID attribute assigned automatically, instead the ID is applied to the name attribute of the control which is why the JavaScript is failing.

I'm using both dynamic HtmlGenericControls and Textboxes.

JavaScript that retrieves the ID, it works when I switch this.id to this.name. However I need to use the ID attribute.

```
document.getElementById('itemID').value = this.id;
```

'itemID' is a hidden input field.

I've tried applying runat="server", clientidmode="static" / "autoID" but no luck so far.

Why is my dynamic controls getting the ID assigned to the name attribute instead of the ID attribute?

Is there something missing that I need to add to make it apply it to the ID attribute?

***If you need any more information just comment below :-)***

*Additional Information*

The web page is using a master page, so the controls are added within content place holders.

I've tried setting the ID in the javascript which added the ID to the attribute correctly but when doing the following the item was still null.

```
this.id = this.name;

TextBox selectedItem = (TextBox)exampleList.FindControl(itemID.Value);
```

Example of the dynamic control after being added:

```
<input name="ctl00$uniqueBody$ctl86" type="text" value="EXAMPLE" runat="server">
```

As you can see the name attribute holds the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create Dynamic Control and want them to have an `id`, you need to specify that when creating them.

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "TextBox1";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Now JavaScript can locate them by their ID, and `FindControl` will also work. FindControl works recursively, so you first need to find the `ContentPlaceHolder` on the Master page, then the `PlaceHolder` and then the dynamically created TextBox.

```
ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
PlaceHolder placeHolder = contentPlaceHolder.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
TextBox textbox = placeHolder.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did this and managed to get around the problem so I'll mark this as the answer. However, this was what I was trying to avoid because it made everything more simplistic if I didn't use set ID's.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of this.ID is not a `string`, but instead is of type `int`, `double`, etc, you'll see problems like this with your code when trying to assign to a string value.  You need to use either `Convert.ToString(this.id)` or `this.id.ToString()`.  The latter cannot handle nulls on its own.

```
document.getElementById('itemID').value = Convert.ToString(this.id);

document.getElementById('itemID').value = this.id.ToString();
```

What you are seeing now instead is the default method, which prints the control `Type`.  If you see the type like that, you likely passed the whole control in and not its value. That suggests you need to check a text value.

```
document.getElementById('itemID').value = this.id.Text;
```

Comment: Sorry, that isn't going to make any difference at this point. This is because this.id is null because the controls ID is set to the name attribute. I'll add extra information to show you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
this.name.id
```

?

Comment: I've just tried this, and no it didn't work :(.  The only difference was itemID.value was equal to "undefined" instead of "".